# Функция с queue(python) не выполняеться While True

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, асинхронность

Функция с queue(python) не выполняеться While True. Я имею ввиду я не могу за 1 секунду записать 5 сообщений в queue для проверки добавления в ту же queue

```
from asyncio import Queue
import asyncio


q = Queue()
async def mama(q):

    while not q.empty():
        try:
            b = await q.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print(b)

        except q.empty():
            None

async def yo():

    while True:
        
        m = input("Введите: ")

        await q.put(m) 
        await mama(q)

asyncio.run(yo())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы хотите вводить данные, отправлять их в очередь, и параллельно раз в 5 секунд из этой очереди их вытаскивать и печатать. Тогда вам нужно не вызывать `mama` из `yo`, а запустить обе корутины через [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

Рабочий вариант:

```
from asyncio import Queue
import asyncio


q = Queue()


async def mama(q):
    # При запуске в очереди пусто, условие not q.empty() ложно, из-за этого в цикл даже не зайдет, меняем на True
    while True:  
        b = await q.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(b)


async def yo():
    while True:
        m = input("Введите: ")
        await q.put(m)
        # Добавляем паузу, чтобы вторая корутина успевала получить управление и вытащить значение из очереди
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def runner():
    # Запускаем две корутины одновременно
    await asyncio.gather(mama(q), yo())


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(runner())
```

Пример ввода-вывода:

```
Введите: 1
Введите: 2
Введите: 3
Введите: 4
Введите: 5
Введите: 6
Введите: 7
Введите: 8
Введите: 9
1
Введите: 10
Введите: 11
Введите: 12
Введите: 13
2
Введите: 14
Введите: 15
Введите: 
...
```

Учитывайте, что `input()` - синхронная функция, и во время ее выполнения асинхронные функции в текущем потоке работать не будут, т.е. если ничего не вводить, обработка очереди выполняться не будет.